# How to get dynamic values in a cell?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, automation

I have a column called "order number" in a sheet. At the start of a day, the value in that cell would be 1. How do I make something that will set the value that every time the cell is cleared, the number increments by 1?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please provide [minimal reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), of what you've tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you mean a cell as A1. You may want to use B1 as a store cell and coloring the text white (hide your storage value/number of edits).

I built a sample here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LUT58HIr3GGvzQ6qlUUGzmKei3yA2vIdxuwrv9FAq_8/edit#gid=0. Try clearing A1 and u will see it increased.

```
// To increment by 1 every time cell is cleared
function onEdit(){
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const edit = ss.getRange('A1').getValue();
  const store = ss.getRange('B1').getValue();
  
  if (edit != '') return;
  var newstore = store + 1;
  ss.getRange('B1').setValue(newstore);
  ss.getRange('A1').setValue(newstore);
}

// To refresh the value to 1 daily
function refresh(){
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  ss.getRange('B1').setValue('1');
  ss.getRange('A1').setValue('1');
}
```

[image: Time Trigger Location]

[image: Time Trigger Setting]

Comment: Yes. Thank you so much. It works fine and I guess it is what I needed. But there's still the issue with it resetting itself to "1" every time it's a new day. I'm thinking of something that when the cell mentioning the date is changed, the A1 cell as you mentioned, gets set to "1". How do I go about that, any tips? Thanks again. :)    @LucasLui888

Comment: Hey great! I would just add a simple function and use the "Triggers" function in apps script to set it to run perhaps everyday at 12:00AM - 1:00AM so it refreshes before you wake up in the morning.

```

Comment: You have to choose the function that you want to run during a time setting. So in this case the onEdit is a reactive function that works as long its active.

The refresh function will only be called based on the trigger. In my example I have set a daily timer but you may check it out to see how you would like to set it.

Comment: @gg0wwrr1 was this able to solve your problem?

Comment: hey! yes, it did help me. thanks